# ClassNotFoundException after running heroku local web; unsure what to include in Procfile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, heroku-cli

My Procfile looks like this:

web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.Main

My directory structure looks like this: src/java/com/Main.java. I'm not even sure how to change my Procfile so it works correctly. The ClassNotFoundException emerges when I run [heroku local web]. Any tips on how to fix? Thank you.

Comment: Why is your location for your source not `src/main/java/com/Main`?